# PHP: Unable to parse specific site using CURL

Tags: php, parsing, curl

This site doesn't return anything when I try to parse it using CURL. Here is my code:

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://casting.backstage.com/jobseekerx/SearchJobs.asp?SubmitToSearch=Search&lctr=1&rvsd=-1&o1=2&p1=1&ipp=10&city=&fromsearchpage=true&cg=11&cg=12&cg=13&cg=14&cg=15&cg=16&cg=17&cg=18&cg=19&cg=20&cg=22&kwrd=&kwdt=1&lcta=1&btnSearch=Run+Search+Now');

print $returned_content;
```

I've never encountered this problem and I've always used this method. I've also tried using Simple DOM Parser and get the same result. This is the URL in question:

http://casting.backstage.com/jobseekerx/SearchJobs.asp?SubmitToSearch=Search&lctr=1&rvsd=-1&o1=2&p1=1&ipp=10&city=&fromsearchpage=true&cg=11&cg=12&cg=13&cg=14&cg=15&cg=16&cg=17&cg=18&cg=19&cg=20&cg=22&kwrd=&kwdt=1&lcta=1&btnSearch=Run+Search+Now

Is there some sort of anti crawl code running on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen what your error is? The `echo curl_error($ch)` allows you to view what exactly is the error you're encountering. On the basis of that, you could then continue to solve the problem in many cases. In this particular case, I added a `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` field and it worked perfectly.

```
<?php
function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
$url = 'http://casting.backstage.com/jobseekerx/SearchJobs.asp?SubmitToSearch=Search&lctr=1&rvsd=-1&o1=2&p1=1&ipp=10&city=&fromsearchpage=true&cg=11&cg=12&cg=13&cg=14&cg=15&cg=16&cg=17&cg=18&cg=19&cg=20&cg=22&kwrd=&kwdt=1&lcta=1&btnSearch=Run+Search+Now';
$returned_content = get_data($url);
print $returned_content;
?>
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the resulting HTML is total junk:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcasting.backstage.com%2Fjobseekerx%2FSearchJobs.asp%3FSubmitToSearch%3DSearch%26lctr%3D1%26rvsd%3D-1%26o1%3D2%26p1%3D1%26ipp%3D10%26city%3D%26fromsearchpage%3Dtrue%26cg%3D11%26cg%3D12%26cg%3D13%26cg%3D14%26cg%3D15%26cg%3D16%26cg%3D17%26cg%3D18%26cg%3D19%26cg%3D20%26cg%3D22%26kwrd%3D%26kwdt%3D1%26lcta%3D1%26btnSearch%3DRun%2BSearch%2BNow&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Wow, interesting. So is it un-parsable because of how poorly the page is put together?

Comment: Probably, you should do an `echo` of `$returned_content` to make sure, but judging from the output I'd say it's just unparsable because of the contents quality.